# Android implement Google maps with fragment

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments

Hi I'm trying to implement the google map in my android application (Android Studio) after the google tutorial here : 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/map#mapfragment

Here is my layout file  (I have added Google play services and api key, there seem to be no error this concerning.)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background1000px"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.zuercher.zuerchertechnik.Display_product">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/box400x50"
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
    android:text="@string/kontakt"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"

    />

<fragment
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:id="@+id/map2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

And here is my java code for the activity :

```
package com.zuercher.zuerchertechnik;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

public class Display_contact extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

@Override

protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_contact);
    MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map2);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {



}
}
```

I'm always getting the almose famous null pointer exception and really have tried a lot of different combinations but I'm getting desperate here.. (Surprisingly following the google tutorial didn't help at all...)
What am I missing here?

Thanks

New added stacktrace code

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                Process: com.zuercher.zuerchertechnik, PID: 19745
                                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.zuercher.zuerchertechnik/com.zuercher.zuerchertechnik.Display_contact}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback)' on a null object reference
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2656)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2721)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:168)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1393)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5753)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback)' on a null object reference
                                                                              at com.zuercher.zuerchertechnik.Display_contact.onCreate(Display_contact.java:41)
                                                                              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6112)
                                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1117)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2609)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2721) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:168) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1393) 
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5753) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
```

Comment: Could you please paste your `NullPointerException` stack trace too?

Comment: addded, sorry for the bad in page organisation but it just 'jumps' to the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use Google Map inside fragments you must use this code :

```
MapFragment= ((MapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map2));

    MapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: try to extends the class Fragment and implement onCreateView , why do you extend FragmentActivity?

Comment: so it's no more extends FragementActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback but just extents Fragment?

Comment: public class Display_contact extends Fragment implements onCreateView does not work as is doesn't recognises onCreateView

Comment: silly me (got no coffee this morning), got it now, will test this right away

Comment: Well I tried it but I don't understand why I would need two classes (and they have two different layouts which is confusing?)

Comment: what do you mean by that , if you do not need `Fragment` just use `Activity` and have one Layout

Comment: Well now I'm lost, I created a second class for the Fragment as mentionned in the link you send me. But I don't get why this is necessairy.

Comment: It is not necessary, it is in your hand if you want `Fragment` or only `Activity` but in your question you have written: Android implement Google maps with fragment. `Fragments` have their own use !

Comment: Sadly I'm more lost then advancing this way, I have no clue how to advance in this state so I will revert it back to the moment I asked this question... I have a simple fragment in my layout and want it to display a google maps... that's all...

Comment: `Fragment` cannot live with out its parent `Activity` , if you don't need `Fragment` , just use `Activity`

Comment: I can't see how to make a view of google map without fragment... I'm really following the example and don't see what you are trying to explain...

Comment: You are confused with activities and fragments , this link that you send me tells : Add a <fragment> element to the activity's layout file to define a Fragment object. In this element, set the android:name attribute to "com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment". This automatically attaches a MapFragment to the activity.

Comment: Well this is exactly what I have done if you look at my layout file.. am I wrong? I know that fragments are like "sub_activities" . But I just dont get why (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment); is null...

Comment: So the title of your question is wrong because you can have Google Map Inside Fragment, for an `Activity` your implementation looks fine to me

Comment: Well then I have no idea how to ask for what I want (no native english speaker).. but still no map in sight.

Comment: if you extend `Activity` or `AppCompatActivity` it may work

Comment: AppCompatActivity  was the right thing!! thanks for your time as this was really some strange behaviour. (Also had a cleaned rebuild).

Comment: @nightslit so I will comment it as an answer, in order future readers can see the solution

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
 static GoogleMap mMap;
```

Before your onCreate and then in your onMapReady

```
 mMap = googleMap;
```

Comment: How must I implement this? if I add this static GoogleMap mMap; It doesn't change the null pointer exception.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `getSupportFragmentManager` rather `getFragmentManager`

Answer (score 0):

You must extend `AppCompatActivity` in order to be able to take the `getFragmentManager` else if you want to use `FragmentActivity` please use `getSupportFragmentManager()`. The documentation of `FragmentActivity` says :

> When using this class as opposed to new platform's built-in fragment and loader support, you must use the getSupportFragmentManager() and getSupportLoaderManager() methods respectively to access those features.